# Many to many relationship with additional created Timestamp column in JPA 2.1

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

My Entities could have one directional relationship between them. 
(Entity is a dummy name)

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer Entity_id;
    ...
    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "Entity2Entity", joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "EntityLeft_id", referencedColumnName="Entity_id"), inverseJoinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "EntityRight_id", referencedColumnName="Entity_id"))
    private Set<Entity> Left2Right = new HashSet<Entity>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "Left2Right")
    private Set<Entity> Right2Left = new HashSet<Entity>();
```

But I want to extend this relationship with an plus Timestamp data column.

[image]

Is ther a way to do this with the EclipseLink 2.5 api?

If not, I read that I can do this with OneToMany connections, but I dont know how.

I created an Entity for Entity2Entity too:

```
@Entity
public class Entity2Entity {
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer Entity2Entity_id;

    private Entity EntityLeft_id;

    private Entity EntityRight_id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private java.util.Date created;
```

But I could not connect them.

Comment: You have a 1-N Entity -> Entity2Entity, and a N-1 Entity2Entity -> Entity; not a M-N. The target of the relations in Entity should be of type Entity2Entity! Right now your "Entity2Entity" is not referenced anywhere, hence is pointless ... until you fix the target of those relations

Comment: My question is about this, how to make it work. So should I put the sets of Left2Right and RightToLeft Entitiy2Entity into my Entity class, and use those in the getLeft2RightEntities() and setLeft2RightEntities() methods indirectly?

Comment: You CANNOT have a M-N with extra columns in the join table, fact. If you need some extra column then you express it as 1-N to Entity2Entity, and N-1 from Entity2Entity to the other side.

Comment: Look at this sample which shows how to do a M-N attributed relationship https://github.com/datanucleus/samples-jpa/tree/master/many_to_many_attributed

Comment: This can help you http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKey.html